# How do I output contents in browser while the script is running?

Tags: php, output

I'm trying to output echo's contents while my script is running. Having read a few tutorials, I do the following:

```
ob_start();

echo "bla bla bla<br>";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5);
echo "bla bla bla<br>";

ob_end_flush();
```

But It doesn't solve the problem. I still get all output after the script finished its work.
Output_buffering is set to Off.

`ob_implicit_flush()` also doesn't help.

I use PhP 5.5 and Safari to display contents.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it's a good idea to be messing with the `request-response` model in this way. Why not try implementing an AJAX based model instead? That way, you make lots of little requests and get lots of little responses, rather than hacking open a single request and response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understend You well this is what you asked for.

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

        echo "<br> Line to show.";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
}

echo "Done.";

ob_end_flush();
```